# With Gold and Ebony, Our Swords Terrify our Enemies

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> What would thou have me do, Oh Lord?
> Our rations run low for the horde.
>
> Risking everything, we'll collect in the rainbow of colors.
> Keep our mistress safe, we'll protect her as a band of brothers.
>
> Who am I?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> bee hive or hive of honey bees

Because:

With Gold and Ebony, Our Swords Terrify our Enemies

> That's what the bees are coloured like and they protect themselves with their stings

Risking everything, we'll collect in the rainbow of colors.

> They risk a lot to collect honey from the flowers (coloured like rainbow)

Keep our mistress safe, we'll protect her as a band of brothers

> And the warrior bees protect the queen bee.

Comment: Sniped! (+1) from me :D

Comment: Good job, you beat El-Guest by a minute.

Comment: I don't think there are any [brothers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drone_(bee)) involved in the protection scheme here though.

Comment: @Bass I'm not quite sure of the gender of the guard bees. You might be right and it could actually be a sisterhood. I'm not a biologist.

Answer (score 7):

I think you are

> worker bees

What would thou have me do, Oh Lord?

> This refers to the Queen Bee.

Our rations run low for the horde.

> A horde of bees in the hive, running out of food/nectar.

Risking everything, we'll collect in the rainbow of colors.

> Risking getting swatted or death after stinging, they collect nectar from a rainbow of coloured flowers.

Keep our mistress safe, we'll protect her as a band of brothers

> The mistress is the Queen and you are the worker bees.

Secret hint:

> The acrostic spells WORK, as in worker bees.

The title:

> Gold and ebony as in the yellow and black stripes of the bees; swords refers to the bees' stingers.